# How to make a bootable USB on Mac?

Tags: usb, windows

Hope you guys are doing well. I want to ask one question to you guys. Please help me out.

I am using Macbook pro. I have a friend who is using Windows 7 but wants to switch to Ubuntu Operating system. He actually got bored of using windows. Now, I do not have any Ubuntu CD but I do have a USB device.

Can you please tell me guys how I can make my USB bootable and run the ubuntu on a windows computer? I want a complete guide please...

Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you look at the [official instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Get the proper architecture i.e 32-bit or 64-bit of the system.

*then;*

1. [Download Ubuntu Desktop](/download/desktop)
2. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).
3. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices.
4. Insert your flash media.
5. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).
6. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN`

   (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).
7. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.iso of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`

   (replace /path/to/downloaded.iso with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./ubuntu.img or ./ubuntu.iso).

   - Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
   - If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
   - If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive

   Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes.

   Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

---

### Alternatively, Using UNetbootin

Download [UNetbootin for mac](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

#### Get the proper architecture i.e 32-bit or 64-bit of the system.

*then;*

[Download Ubuntu Desktop](/download/desktop) *(if you dont already have one)*

After this, run UNetbootin select the ISO file, select a target drive (USB Drive or Hard Disk). After the installation, don't restart as prompted, since this is not for MAC but rather for windows. Just safely remove the USB and you can try it in a Windows PC if you have acess to any.

Comment: Thanks CheddieMerai, I have installed the software. there are lots of things. Its hard to understand. Can you please explain a bit clearly?

Comment: Can you point out exactly what you need clarification with? I'll gladly assist the best I can.

Comment: ok. I have launched the program. There is a thing named 'Distribution'. and another thing called 'Diskimage'. And under Diskimage something called ISO. should I select that one?

Comment: There is a Radio button with the text _Distribution_ next to it. If you don't have a Diskimage then you would select this option so the image would be downloaded. On the other hand, there is another Radio button at the bottom with the text _Diskimage_. You would select this option **if** you have an image *iso*. Please be careful when selecting the appropriate drive. Anything else you may like answered?

Answer (score 0):

This link will lead you to a site with a free program to do a USB on your Mac and discusses the problem. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/ I'm not sure it is exactly what you need, give it a look.